# Is it possible to convert a string into a node?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to create a random name generator from a set list of names (from 1-10). I have assigned an id to each name (from "s01" to "s10") and am trying to write some JavaScript to randomly choose one from the list. This is what I have so far:

```
if (action === 'who') {
    console.log("who");
    let num = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1);
    console.log(num);
    if (num === 10) {
        numb = s10.textContent;
    } else {
        num = ("s0"+num);
        console.log(num);
        numb = num.textContent;
    }
console.log(numb);
```

But I'm getting console.logs as "undefined," unless the number generated was 10, and then it is fine.

I am trying to convert what comes up as num into the id but I'm not sure how to do it.

Comment: I would re-read your else branch, what do you expect `textContent` of  a string would be? Depending on where your s01...s10 is defined you might want to get it with `document.querySelector('#' + num)` or something similar? Or are they variable names?

Comment: so, for example, if s06.textContent is "Kevin," that's what I want to be returned. The else branch is definitely where my confusion lies.

Comment: @Icepickle What you're missing is the element IDs automatically become global variables.

Comment: @Barmar then shouldn't your response be `global[num].textContent`? :)

Comment: No, because I consider it poor style to depend on that, and `document.getElementById()` is the idiomatic way.

Comment: the IDs are defined within the html

Comment: @Icepickle BTW, it would be `window[num]`

Comment: @Barmar that's fine, I just wanted to help the OP think critically about the code written :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you write

```
num = ("s0" + num);
```

you're just creating a string, it doesn't try to use that as the name of a variable. So it doesn't access the node in the variable `s06`.

Use `document.getElementById()` to get the element with a specific ID, rather than trying to access it as a variable. You can use string concatenation to create the argument.

```
var id = num < 10 ? "s0" + num : "s" + num;
var element = document.getElementById(id);
var numb = element.textContent;
```

Comment: Thank you, that makes sense!